# Error -66680 (kAudioQueueErr_InvalidDevice) from AudioQueueStart in SwiftUI / Swift 5.3

Tags: swift, audiotoolbox, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to record audio e.g. from the Macbook's internal microphone. This is my code:

```
func record() {
    let sampleRate = 48000
    let numChannels = 1
    var inFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription(mSampleRate: Double(sampleRate),
                                               mFormatID: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
                                               mFormatFlags: kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked,
                                               mBytesPerPacket: UInt32(numChannels * MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size),
                                               mFramesPerPacket: 1,
                                               mBytesPerFrame: UInt32(numChannels * MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size),
                                               mChannelsPerFrame: UInt32(numChannels),
                                               mBitsPerChannel: UInt32(8 * MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size),
                                               mReserved: UInt32(0))

    var inAQ: AudioQueueRef? = nil;

    var status = AudioQueueNewInput(&inFormat, callback, nil, nil, nil, 0, &inAQ)
    print("AudioQueueNewInput returned " + status.description)

    status = AudioQueueStart(inAQ!, nil)
    print("AudioQueueStart returned " + status.description)
}
```

I took most of it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519077/get-microphone-input-using-audio-queue-in-swift-3) answer. However, I'm getting a different error. The output is:

> AudioQueueNewInput returned 0 
> 2021-01-02 13:41:49.341243+0100 ocean[39484:6411401] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002c79880> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46 
> 2021-01-02 13:41:49.408830+0100 ocean[39484:6411401]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: opening the plug-in failed, Error: 2003329396 (what) 
> 2021-01-02 13:41:49.472141+0100 ocean[39484:6411401] [AQ] AudioQueueObject.cpp:1179:BuildConverter: AudioConverterNew returned -50 
> AudioQueueStart returned -50

OSStatus -50 indicates a bad parameter. Which of my parameters is bad?

EDIT: I had a different audio input set in the system preferences. I switched to the internal microphone and am now getting a different error:

> AudioQueueNewInput returned 0 
> 2021-01-02 14:55:03.415688+0100 ocean[40044:6458085] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000035de820> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46 
> 2021-01-02 14:55:03.482119+0100 ocean[40044:6458085]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: opening the plug-in failed, Error: 2003329396 (what) 
> 2021-01-02 14:55:03.483443+0100 ocean[40044:6458085] [aqme] AQMEIO.cpp:352:AQMEIOManager_FindIOUnit: error -66680 finding/initializing Device.AQDefaultInput 
> AudioQueueStart returned -66680

-66680 means invalid device. Any hints on why that is? I updated the title, but I'd still like to know why the other audio input rejects these parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by enabling "Audio Input" in Signing & Capabilities of my Target. It actually solved it for all audio input devices.